# Relation between the lenghts of unequal chords and their distances from the centre

Tags: geometry

Is there any proportional relation between  the lenghts of unequal chords and their respective distances from the centre of a circumference?

Comment: The lengths of the unequal chords?

Comment: Yes, I meant the lenghts

Comment: A bit of Pythagoras involving half the length of each chord (L/2), the distance from the centre (d) and the radius (r) would suggest the relationship between 2 chord lengths is not a proportionate one. Have a look:)

Answer (score 0):

Draw a sketch of a tangent and chord at any point of a circle radius R. If chord length is $L$ and minimum distance to chord center from center of circle is $h$,

$$ \sin \theta = \dfrac{L}{2R}, \cos \theta = \dfrac{h}{R},$$

where $\theta$ is angle between tangent and chord.